# How to do Hit testing in GDI+ for rotated shapes with real shape measurements (inches)?

Tags: c#, winforms, math, gdi+, mouse

Given I have a canvas that contains many shapes, lets say rectangles for now.

Each shape has a location (inches), size(inches) and rotation angle(degrees).

When a mouse click event happen inside the canvas for a location (x,y) in pixels.

I want to check if the clicked mouse position is inside/within a specific shape, considering the rotation angle and measurement unit conversion.

Can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer (I have to convert al measurements to pixels to make sure it will calculate correctly):

```
public static bool HitTest(Rectangle bounds, float angle, Point location)
        {
            if (angle == 0) return bounds.Contains(location);

            using (Matrix matrix = new Matrix())
            {
                matrix.RotateAt(angle, Center(bounds));
                using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
                {
                    path.AddRectangle(bounds);
                    path.Transform(matrix);
                    return path.IsVisible(location.X, location.Y);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is awfully short on details, I can only provide a generic answer.  Do it mathematically is the fastest way.  Rotation can make that difficult.

You can solve it slowly but easily by using a hit-test bitmap.  Render the shapes to a Bitmap, using the same code you now use to render it to the screen.  But now using a color that encodes the shape number.  Hit testing is now simple and quick with GetPixel().  Be careful to turn off image enhancement settings, like anti-aliasing.  Render it to the screen first and take a good look at the pixels with ZoomIt.

Comment: I was about to give a similar answer, it is the best solution for arbitrarily shaped objects (or sprites!).

Comment: this will become very very slow if my canvas contains hundreds of shapes

Comment: It will be exactly as slow as painting them to the screen.  Of course, you make the bitmap only once, not over and over again.  Like you did in your post that you marked as the answer.

Comment: Update: I edited the question to clarify it, so that it can be helpful for someone in the future searching for the same problem.